# flash doesn't load when hosted on windows 2008 server, I have to righ click -> play to run it

Tags: windows, apache-flex, flash, adobe, windows-server-2008

I have a website on IIS7, when hosted in windows 7 the flash was loading ok, but when I put him on win 2008 server they don't load fully, I just shows a gray square (without the loading), and to make it work I have to right click and click play

anybody knows how to fix this ?

Comment: Which browser are you testing with? I remember some issues with IE a long time ago, where you had to click to run "active" content in IE.

Comment: @ilikeorangutans mozilla firefox, and I have this issue only when the swf is hosted on windows server 2008

Answer (score 0):

could you reinstall firefox to latest version?

and/or try from your another/LAN computer to access this flash application?

Comment: @Omu, great, did you try to reinstall firefox? or did you try it from private mode in firefox? i think its a feature from about:config limitation of firefox.